# The "signed up for beta" stat is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

Currently, [Skeptics' Area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptics) claims that:

> **committed users**
>
> 241 users committed
>   4.6% signed up for beta
>   0% fulfilled commitment
>
> **followers**
>
> 173 users followed
>   1.7% signed up for beta

That does not add up. There are 127 registered users on Skeptics.
Even if you remove the users who did not commit (Jeff, Rebecca, Geoff, etc.), you still end up with far more than the tiny portion of users who allegedly signed up for beta.

It doesn't look like it's a problem of simply outdated information. Yesterday, around this time of the day, there were at least 107 registered users. So, unless it's not updated daily, that can't be the problem. Moreover, if it's updated daily at 0 UTC like practically everything else in SEN, then it should be off by only two users (only Trish Hann and Dori signed up for beta since yesterday).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right – the signed-up-for-beta percentages were way off. A while ago, we started only tracking beta users with >= 200 rep, so as a consequence, these percentages only reflected followers/committers who signed up for the beta *and* had >= 200 rep.

This is fixed now, and the numbers are updated hourly.

Comment: Looks like the bug has been revived.. can you please look into it?

Comment: I assume you're referring to [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115114/weird-commitment-percentage-values-on-area-51)? It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

The percentage fits very well if you only count users with more than 200 reputation. It seems it is not sufficient to only create an account to be counted in this statistic.

Answer (score 0):

That statistic is only updated daily. At the time it was last update, there weren't as many registered users.

Comment: I considered that yesterday, when I first noticed the problem, which is why I waited until today to be sure. I edited my question to reflect that.