# Weird commitment percentage values on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

I was looking at some other proposals to compare the statistics to the recently failed proposals and noticed that some values looked pretty unrealistic.

For [Programmers.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related) it shows more than 100% of committed users signed up for the beta

[image]

and for [Sharepoint.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/sharepoint) it shows only 3.8% of committed users signed up, which sounds unbelievably low.

[image]

Also [Electrical Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651/electrical-engineering):

[image]

I suspect that there might be some error in the calculations here.

Comment: 101.4% signed up for beta?  That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed now.

There was a bug in the way we computed %-signed-up-for-beta stats for sites that never had a *private* beta: [Startups](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business), [Electrical Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651/electrical-engineering), [SharePoint](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/sharepoint), and [Judaism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning). [Programmers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related) was affected by an unrelated glitch and has been fixed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug.

- [x] users commited
- [y]% signed up for beta
- [z]% fulfilled commitment

My interpretation is:

**x** - the amount of users who joined the site when it was in proposal stage, i.e. committing themselves to the cause. Think it's totally clear.

**y** - the percentage of users **from those who committed** who actually joined the Beta stage by following the email they got and registering in the site, maybe also it requires at least one post to count.

**z** - the percentage of users from those who signed up for the beta who posted enough, as written when committing:

> I commit to participate actively in [site name here] for at least three months, especially during the private beta, and to ask or answer at least ten questions.

So it means, how many users really had at least ten posts.

I might be wrong of course, would be glad if someone will come and correct my above assumptions.

Comment: But 101.4% signing up for the beta? (Unless their level of commitment is taken into account and they are just extra committed ;) )

Comment: @Bart Maybe it's percentage from the required 200 - as 208 comitted, it's possible. If so, it might be display bug.

Comment: Ah, see, that sounds logical.

Comment: I don't believe that there were proposals where only 5% of the users who committed even signed up, that is just too far away from the usual 60-80% of the other proposals. I didn't check every proposal, but form the ones I checked there were no values from 5-50%, most where higher than 60%.

Comment: @Fabian Hmm.. so either [the bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114802/percentage-of-signed-up-users-for-beta-is-wrong-on-area-51) was not really fixed, or maybe by fixing it, they revived [this older bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80739/the-signed-up-for-beta-stat-is-wrong).